# how to select value by key in json object with postgrsql

Tags: json, postgresql

i've JSON object and i need to use it in PostgreSQL function to use it in my project and i need get value from json object and use it in insert or update query

my simple object

```
{
    "Customer_IntegrationCode": "558889999",
    "XretialOrderCode": "000020430",
    "ShippingAddress": "Cairo, Nasr City, 01128777733",
    "ShippingAddress_IntegrationCode": null,
    "PaymentOption": 1,
    "CreationDate": "2021-01-04T07:38:57.033Z",
    "Total": 73.0,
    "Currency": "EGP",
    "Note": null,
    "ShippingCost": 15.0,
    "CODFee": 25.0,
    "ShipmentProvider": null, 
    "Plateform": 1, 
    "SubTotal": 33.0,
    "TotalDiscountAmount_PerOrderLevel": 0,
    "OriginalSubTotal": 33.0,
    "TaxPercentage": null,
    "TaxValue": null,
    "Store_IntegrationCode": "1234567",
    "OrderItems": [
        {
            "productCode": "12345678",
            "SKU": "23456789",
            "Qty": 3,
            "UnitPrice": 11.0,
            "NetPrice": 11.0,
            "SKUDiscount": 0,
            "Total": 33.0,
            "ShipmentCost": 0.0,
            "SubTotal": 33.0
            
        },
                {
            "productCode": "999999",
            "SKU": "988888",
            "Qty": 3,
            "UnitPrice": 11.0,
            "NetPrice": 11.0,
            "SKUDiscount": 0,
            "Total": 33.0,
            "ShipmentCost": 0.0,
            "SubTotal": 33.0
            
        }
    ]
}
```

how to get value for total in  PostgreSQL select query??
i tried this code but not working

```
WITH my_table ( jsonblob ) AS ( VALUES ( '{
        "Customer_IntegrationCode": "558889999",
        "XretialOrderCode": "000020430",
        "ShippingAddress": "Cairo, Nasr City, 01128777733",
        "ShippingAddress_IntegrationCode": null,
        "PaymentOption": 1,
        "CreationDate": "2021-01-04T07:38:57.033Z",
        "Total": 73.0,
        "Currency": "EGP",
        "Note": null,
        "ShippingCost": 15.0,
        "CODFee": 25.0,
        "ShipmentProvider": null, 
        "Plateform": 1, 
        "SubTotal": 33.0,
        "TotalDiscountAmount_PerOrderLevel": 0,
        "OriginalSubTotal": 33.0,
        "TaxPercentage": null,
        "TaxValue": null,
        "Store_IntegrationCode": "1234567",
        "OrderItems": [
        {
        "productCode": "12345678",
        "SKU": "23456789",
        "Qty": 3,
        "UnitPrice": 11.0,
        "NetPrice": 11.0,
        "SKUDiscount": 0,
        "Total": 33.0,
        "ShipmentCost": 0.0,
        "SubTotal": 33.0
        
        },
        {
        "productCode": "999999",
        "SKU": "988888",
        "Qty": 3,
        "UnitPrice": 11.0,
        "NetPrice": 11.0,
        "SKUDiscount": 0,
        "Total": 33.0,
        "ShipmentCost": 0.0,
        "SubTotal": 33.0
        
        }
        ]
        }
    ' :: jsonb ) ) SELECT
my_table -> Total
FROM
    my_table
```

i need to get value using key from object

thnx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please always **minimize** your examples. For that question you don't need to put all of your attributes into the query. One or two would be enough. More make the query uncomfortable to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=39c1bb7afb8e5b18a167d73fe87932ad)

You have to query the column not the table for the attribute. Furthermore the attribute needs to be of type `text` or similar:

```
SELECT 
    (jsonblob ->> 'Total')::numeric
FROM my_table
```

Comment: thnx @S-Man working but it return vule with "" can i remove it?? ,, for example in total it return "73.0" and i need it like this 73.0

Comment: The `->` returns type `json`. If you want to get another type, you have to cast it. First use the `->>` instead, which returns type `text` which can be cast into type `numeric`, for example. (`jsonblog ->> 'Total')::numeric`